# The use of Keras self-attention module

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series

This question calls people to share their personal experiences with `keras_self_attention` module.

I also summarized the problems I encountered and the solutions I found or received from answers.

---

**Background**

I am building a classifier using time series data. The input is in shape of (batch, step, features).

The flawed codes are shown below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout,Bidirectional,Masking,LSTM
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention

X_train = np.random.rand(700, 50,34)
y_train = np.random.choice([0, 1], 700)
X_test = np.random.rand(100, 50, 34)
y_test = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units, dropout=dropout, recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout)))
model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                        verbose=1
                        )

yhat = model.predict_prob(X_test)
```

**Problems**

*1. The model raised an IndexError at the `SeqSelfAttention` layer.*

```
Solution: This problem was because the `return_sequences` in the last `LSTM` layer was not set to `True`
```

*2. The model raised a `ValueError` before the `Dense` layer due to the shape incompatible problem.*

```
Solution: The solution is to add a `Flatten()` layer before `Dense` layer.
```

*3. How do `Muplicative attention` and `Multi-head` work?

*4. Does stacking multiple layers of `self_attention`(SA) work for improving accuracy? Should it be like LSTM+LSTM+SA+SA or LSTM+SA+LSTM+SA?

Comment: Can you specify what exact error message show?

Comment: @AIFahim I have posted the screenshot of the error

Answer (score 5):

*It seems that the `SeqSelfAttention` layer is expecting all the time-steps.*

i.e. `return_sequences=True`

 Same is shown in the home page example. [*Link*](https://pypi.org/project/keras-self-attention/)

```py
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout,Bidirectional,Masking,LSTM
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention

X_train = np.random.rand(700, 50,34)
y_train = np.random.choice([0, 1], 700)
X_test = np.random.rand(100, 50, 34)
y_test = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(20, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works as I somehow missed that point and I have updated the question as a ValueError occurred at the Dense layer. With referring to the model summary the output of the self_attention layer is still in time series.  The homepage link used `Dense` without specifying the `activation function` so I tried that way but the same error popped out

Comment: Please add a Flatten layer before Dense. I am suggesting you only remedy of errors and cause. I have no idea what this module does. Just an FYI

Comment: Thank you for your help, you deserved the bounty and I will keep this question open and wait for other answers to share more experiences on the use of this module.

Comment: I will suggest you close this Question and Post a separate one with the precise questions adding a reference to this question.